# How can I reorder these F# functions to make sense?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, mutual-recursion

I thought I'd be getting along alright with F# since I'm decent at Haskell, but I feel like I'm being stumped by dead simple issues.  I have some parsing code for a simple JSON parser, like this:

```
let rec parseObject tokens = function
 | '"' :: cs -> parseString tokens cs
 | ':' :: cs -> parseValue tokens cs
 | '}' :: cs -> tokens, cs
 ...

let rec parseValue tokens = function
 | c :: cs when Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) -> parseValue tokens cs
 | '{' :: cs -> parseObject tokens cs
 ...
```

That won't work, because parseObject doesn't know about parseValue.  Can't reverse them either or I'd get the opposite problem.  So what am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You define mutually recursive function using the `and` keyword. Like this:

```
let rec parseObject tokens = function
 | '"' :: cs -> parseString tokens cs
 | ':' :: cs -> parseValue tokens cs
 | '}' :: cs -> tokens, cs
 ...

and parseValue tokens = function
 | c :: cs when Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) -> parseValue tokens cs
 | '{' :: cs -> parseObject tokens cs
 ...
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't even know "mutually recursive functions" were a thing that you had to indicate.  Haskell has spoiled me.  Thank you so much, would have taken me forever to understand that was the problem otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing your second `let rec` with `and` to define a set of [mutually recursive functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233232.aspx).